# Text alignment within the definition of a function?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How would I format the following such that the text is aligned left rather than centre?

```
$$|x|\vcentcolon=\Bigg\{\begin{tabular}{cc}$x$ if $x>0$\\$-x$ if $x<0$\end{tabular}$$
```

Comment: Change cc to ll

Comment: And don't use $$.

Comment: Better yet, load the `amsmath` package and use a `cases` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fiddling with the arguments of `tabular`, just load the `amsmath` package and use a `cases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads 'amsmath' automatically; provides '\coloneqq` macro
\begin{document}
\[
|x|\coloneqq
\begin{cases}
 x & \text{if $x\ge0$}\\
-x & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Oh, and don't use `$$` to start and terminate an unnumbered display math environment in a LaTeX document. See the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for a discussion of why `\[ ... \]` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

A variant with `empheq` and `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq} % loads mathtools, which extends amsmath and  provides the '\coloneqq` macro

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left = \lvert x\rvert \coloneq q\empheqlbrace]{alignat*=2}
  & x &\quad & \text{if $x\ge0$}\\
  -&x & & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]